# Can one overload operators in Scala companion objects?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, companion-object

I would like to overload operators in a Scala companion object. Is something like this possible?

```
case class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double)

object Complex {
  def +(c1: Complex, c2: Complex): Complex = Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary)
  def add(c1: Complex, c2: Complex): Complex = c1 + c2
}
```

The above gives an error on the `add` method saying `Cannot resolve symbol +`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to define methods inside case class

```
case class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) {
  def +(c2: Complex): Complex = Complex(real + c2.real, imaginary + c2.imaginary)
  def add(c2: Complex): Complex = this + c2
}
```

or define extension methods if you don't have access to the case class

```
case class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) 

implicit class ComplexOps(c1: Complex) {
  def +(c2: Complex): Complex = Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary)
  def add(c2: Complex): Complex = c1 + c2
}
```

or fix method `add` in object

```
case class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) 

object Complex {
  def +(c1: Complex, c2: Complex): Complex = Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary)
  def add(c1: Complex, c2: Complex): Complex = Complex.+(c1, c2)
}
```